# UpdatePanel stops CommandArgument from Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web

I have a button nested inside an update panel which has a CommandArgument tied to it. This calls a method which updates some label and text in an area not contained in the UpdatePanel. If I comment out the update panel the button works correctly so I know it is coming from the update panel. Anyone know how I can pass this through?

protected void Button_Command(object sender, 
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //update textboxes and labels here
}

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div>


                                    <asp:DataList ID="dListItems" runat="server" DataKeyField="PRODUCT_ID" RepeatColumns="4"
                                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" CellPadding="4">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            No Record Found....!
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" 
                                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'  CausesValidation="False"  
                                                            CssClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
                                                            OnCommand="Button_Command"   
                                                            /></span></span></p>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>

                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which updates some label and text in an area not contained in the
>   UpdatePanel

That's the problem. UpdatePanel will only update what is within and not what is outside. Try to put those control also the UpdatePanel and see them worked

Comment: Thanks for those who have problems with this also, put your update panel into the master page level and all your code will work. Thanks!